# Output Size of Mixture Density Networks

Tags: neural-networks, normal-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution, arithmetic

I am working on a neural network in which the final output layer will be a Mixture Density Network (MDN), but am confused about the shape of the values that final layer should return.

In the paper in which he introduced MDN's, Christopher Bishop writes: "Note that the total number of network outputs [created by a final MDN layer] is given by (c+2) * m, as compared with the usual c outputs for a network used in a conventional manner" [[bottom-most line on page 7](https://publications.aston.ac.uk/373/1/NCRG_94_004.pdf)].

I have seen some papers that use MDN's, though, that seem to create a different number of outputs. The Master's thesis "Dancing with Deep Learning", for example, has c = 75, m = 25, but the output size is 3775 (2cm + m) [[bottom of page 22](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwj3xvzQjp_eAhUrhOAKHRZHDi8QFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fupcommons.upc.edu%2Fbitstream%2Fhandle%2F2117%2F106478%2FDancingWithDeepLearning.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0mXoINU06SwNoUlu_FB9bv)].

I have also seen Python implementations of MDN layers in Keras in which the output size appears to be [(c+2)*m](https://github.com/omimo/Keras-MDN/blob/master/kmdn/mdn.py) and [2cm + m](https://github.com/cpmpercussion/keras-mdn-layer/blob/master/mdn/__init__.py).

Am I misinterpreting things, or are these implementations genuinely creating different sized outputs. If they *are* creating different size outputs, what are the motivations for each style output?

Intuitively, I would expect the number of sigmas generated to equal the number of mus, as we need equal shapes to parameterize m Gaussians, but this does not seem to jive with Bishop's (c+2) * m equation.

Edit: I had a talk with two brilliant physicists on campus today, and they helped me see the MDN layer as more of a mathematical construct than a piece of software with a particular architecture. As a mathematical construct, the MDN layer with `c` sigmas just produces uniform variance around each value in `c` for a given distribution in the Gaussian mixture. If we find this confining, we can learn a unique sigma for each value in `c`, which is what the model with output weights 2cm + m above is doing. I believe this solves the riddle.

Comment: What do $c$ and $m$ refer to?

Comment: Sorry, `c` is the number of outputs the network would predict were there no MDN layer, and `m` is the number of Gaussians to include in the MDN layer.